# ES not listening to external requests

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, netstat

I have an e2 ubuntu instance running elasticsearch, and although it works fine locally, I can't connect from a windows pc using `curl http://ipaddress:9200/` (error is "unable to connect to the remote server").

I've set up Apache on the same ubuntu instance and `curl http://ipaddress:80/` works from the same windows machine, & I can ping the instance with no trouble.
My amazon security group allows tcp access to all ports from all IP addresses.

I think it's an ES config issue, although the only lines I've added to elasticsearch.yml are:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```

I've noticed something strange when I run netstat, there's a 1 in the Local address for ports 9200 and 9300 (ES ports) - would this block my external request, and if so how do I change this?

```
   ubuntu@ESServer$ netstat -nat
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0    448 (AWS PRIVATE IP):22     (MY IP):63572           ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9200                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9300                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: Do you have an internet access? Do you have an external IP?

Comment: Internet access isn't a problem, I can access port 80. I am using the external IP in my curl commands

Comment: Do you have IPTables enables? Can you show the output from `iptables -L`?

Comment: sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: apologies for the formatting. Basically, iptables is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your elasticsearch process is bind to localhost. Try to run it like this:

```
bin/elasticsearch --network.host _non_loopback_
```

Since 2.0 elasticsearch binds to localhost. For that reason you are not able to access it.

The reasons behind this change is explained in [this blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-unplugged)

Comment: Thanks! I actually changed the network.host setting in elasticsearch.yml to 0:0:0:0 and restarted the instance a few minutes ago, which worked. However, I've marked this as the answer seeing as after reading the documentation below, it's evident your approach would work too.