# ElasticSearch can't connect by host browser

Tags: elasticsearch

I made ElasticSearch server by Berksfile.

Then it install to ElasticSearch 2.1.0.

I try to do this command by guest OS.

```
[vagrant@vm1-berkshelf ~]$ curl http://localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "vm1-berkshelf",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.1.0",
    "build_hash" : "72cd1f1a3eee09505e036106146dc1949dc5dc87",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-11-18T22:40:03Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.3.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

It can connect.
But if host OS connect to this server, it can't connect.

```
curl http://192.168.33.12:9200
```

I try check about Iptables, but it looks like available to all port.

```
[vagrant@vm1-berkshelf ~]$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES not listening to external requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480618/es-not-listening-to-external-requests)

Answer (score 2):

Since the 2.0 release, Elasticsearch [binds to localhost by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_network_changes.html#_bind_to_localhost) (as a security measure to prevent your node from connecting to other nodes on the network without you knowing it).

So what you need to do is simply to edit your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file and change the `network.bind_host` setting like this:

```
network.bind_host: 0
```

Then, you need to restart your node and it will be accessible from a remote host using your curl command.